# React Typescript Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(App) /> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I was developing an App where I use Firebase as an Authentication system of the App, an when I try to implement the routes of the app, I start to get the above title error.

I'm using withRouter funtion, to encapsulate my App component.

So the code of my App.tsx file is the following:

```
import React, { FC, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  Route,
  Switch,
  useHistory,
  withRouter,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

import Header from "./components/sections/Header";
import SignUp from "./components/pages/SignUp";
import SignIn from "./components/pages/SignIn";
import ForgotPassword from "./components/pages/ForgotPassword";
import Homepage from "./components/pages/Homepage";
import Dashboard from "./components/pages/Dashboard";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/auth/PrivateRoute";
import PublicRoute from "./components/auth/PublicRoute";
import Loader from "./components/UI/Loader";
import firebase from "./firebase/config";
import {
  getUserById,
  setLoading,
  setNeedVerification,
} from "./store/actions/authActions";
import { RootState } from "./store";

const App: FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { loading } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);
  let history = useHistory();
  // Check if user exists
  // App.tsx
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true));
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        await dispatch(getUserById(user.uid));
        if (user.emailVerified) {
          history.push("/homepage");
        } else {
          history.push("/signin");
          dispatch(setNeedVerification());
        }
      }
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  function Routes() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <PublicRoute path="/signup" component={SignUp} exact />
        <PublicRoute path="/signin" component={SignIn} exact />
        <PublicRoute path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} exact />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact />
        <PublicRoute path="/homepage" component={Homepage} exact />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Routes />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default withRouter(App);
```

`So I think that have to be realated with the configuration of Route library into the main component of the app.

What I missing??

Take thankss in advance !

Comment: as you are using `useHistory`, you don't need `withRouter` isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App` is the component rendering the `Router` so `App` itself can't use anything that requires a `Router` context higher up in the React tree.

The solution is to move the `Router` higher in the React tree, i.e. wrap `App` in the `Router`. Once `App` is being rendered by a `Router` and since you are using the `useHistory` hook there will be no need to decorate with the `withRouter` HOC.

App

```
const App: FC = () => {
  ...

  function Routes() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <PublicRoute path="/signup" component={SignUp} exact />
        <PublicRoute path="/signin" component={SignIn} exact />
        <PublicRoute path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} exact />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact />
        <PublicRoute path="/homepage" component={Homepage} exact />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index where `App` is rendered.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from '../App';

...

<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```